# How can locate aapt from the terminal

Tags: android, aapt

I have been running the command `aapt list -a` on an APK file but i keep having the error:

> appt command not found.

I have check the Android-SDKs built-tools and the aapt file exist in the location.

Please, what do i need to do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set path.

Go to system properties -->Environment variables -->New/Edit "PATH"

Add C:\\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Refer [How to Add set path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: I have set the path, "export PATH=$PATH:/android-sdks/build-tools/23.0.2"   but i still get another error. -- Bash: /android-sdks/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: No such file or directory

Comment: Thank you i have solved the problem. I installed the 32bit libraries and its now working.

Comment: @Ibro Sounds Good. Happy coding.